# Creating dynamic Highcharts based on an array

Tags: php, mysql, variables, highcharts

To sort off cap what I'm doing.. I have a loop that creates a table from information pulled from my database. I've setup a superglobal variable inside the loop that assigns one of my table field values to the variable; that part works no problem.

The problem is when I try to call that variable inside the highcharts function, it just doesn't work. The charts don't show up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $container = $('$global_var');
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            chart: {
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                        [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
                        ]
                },
                borderWidth: 2,
                plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
                plotShadow: true,
                plotBorderWidth: 1
            }
        });

         var chart1  = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: $container,
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },

            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
                pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
            }]
        });

    });
    </script>
```

In the table that's created, I have a `<div>` inserted with a dynamic ID (same values as the array I'm attempting to use with the highcharts function), which also works. The only issue is that I can't seem to pass the variable to the renderTo part of the highcharts function.

Here's how I'm declaring my superglobal variable inside my table loop (again, works fine):

```
$GLOBALS['a'] = $row['Name'] . $temp_array;
```

TL;DR.. If anyone knows how to pass a variable to renderTo in the Highcharts function I'd really love to know how you do it. Hopefully this is enough info, but if not I'll gladly provide what is requested. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What do you get if you output $container just before you create the chart ?

Answer (score 0):

In renderTo you need to add string not object as you return.

So it should be

```
 var $container = 'global_var', //id of container, string
```

and in the chart

```
 chart: {
            renderTo: $container,
        },
```

If you would like to combine js variable with string from php variable it should be something like:

```
var $container = '<?php echo $variable ?>',
```

Comment: `var $container = '$GLOBALS['global_name']';`

`chart: {


        renderTo: $container,
   

     },`
That's what I'd like to use when declaring the variable. The variable global_name is being assigned multiple names in a loop (in a different function), so I'd like to be able to call the name (since that's what I put as my div id's) with $GLOBALS. However, that doesn't seem to work. A locally declared variable will, but $GLOBALS['global_name'] doesn't.

Comment: But you cannot mixed this in this way, because your "variable" is stirng and it is not parsed.